# Vue3, child component doesn't render dynamic string value

Tags: vuejs3

When I import HelloWorld component into App.vue, I'm unable to see the content of contenutoHeader.

HelloWorld:

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ contenutoHeader }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
const contenutoHeader = "Sto funzionando";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
};
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <HelloWorld />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";
</script>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to review any tutorial on basic Vue.js reactivity

Answer (score -1):

You need to add your state to the `data`, like so:

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ contenutoHeader }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",

  data () {
      return {
           contenutoHeader: "Sto funzionando"
      }

  }
};
</script>
```

Anything within the `data` is reactive and can be used in your `template`

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using the composition API. What's the alternative to this?

Comment: the alternative is to use ref, for example const contenutoHeader = ref("Sto funzionando")

Comment: Your example isn't in the full composition API format (when you use <script setup>... However you can use the composition API format in the object export version like so:
`<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  setup() {
     const contenutoHeader = ref("Sto funzionando");
  }
};
</script>`